# Screen Orientation Handling

Tags: android, android-orientation

In my application, most of the activities has fixed layout - portrait.
So I've mentioned in `manifest`:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity5"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

But in one or two activities I've to show landscape layout also, in such a way that by default the activity opens in portrait mode. But if user tilts the phone to left/right it changes to landscape. (also if user rotates the phone to upside down, activity should not go to portrait mode).

That is, basically, I want orientation change in 3-way. Default(Potrait) & Left-Right(Landscape).

So, what changes do I need to do in my code & xmls?

1. Should I choose "sensorPortrait" OR "sensorLandscape"
2. Should I use android:configChanges="orientation"

I tried few steps, but they are throwing null pointer exception.

I dont know what I'm missing.

P.S. Both orientation have different layouts.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

1) Just remove `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, and

2) In your code, in onCreate(), add `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

--(UNRELATED) SIDE NOTE--

To force landscape use this:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.activity5" 
          android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write to Main.class(OnCreate):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```